# componentRestrictions doesn't seem to have an effect with AutocompleteService.getQueryPredictions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

(tried to make a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sujatuzaro/edit?html,js,output) but it won't load the Google libraries)

Loading this version of the API libraries:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&libraries=places&callback=onAPILoaded

Running this JS:

```
function runQuery(country) {
  var request = {
    input: 'london',
    componentRestrictions: {country: country},
  };

  var callback = function(predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
      return;
    }
    var resultsString = predictions.reduce(function (prev, current) {
      return prev + "\n" + current.description;
    }, "RESULTS FOR " + country + "\n--------------\n");
    console.log(resultsString);
  };

  var service = new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  service.getQueryPredictions(request, callback);
}

// on api loaded...
function onAPILoaded() {
  runQuery('uk');
  runQuery('ca');
}
```

And getting this output

```
RESULTS FOR uk
--------------

London, United Kingdom
London, ON, Canada
London Borough of Hillingdon, United Kingdom
London Eye, London, United Kingdom
London Bridge, London, United Kingdom

RESULTS FOR ca
--------------

London, United Kingdom
London, ON, Canada
London Borough of Hillingdon, United Kingdom
London Eye, London, United Kingdom
London Bridge, London, United Kingdom
```

The problem is that it doesn't look like componentRestrictions is doing anything - the results are the same regardless of the country code. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `componentRestrictions`-property for a [QueryAutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest)

The `componentRestrictions`-property applies to a [AutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompletionRequest) (which will be used with `getPlacePredictions()`)

Comment: Yes, that was it, simply changing service.getPlacePredictions for service. getQueryPredictions does the job